# Unable to create notifications in android Pie

Tags: android, notifications, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to implement notifications for my android application, its working fine on almost all versions except android 9 (I didn't check it on android 8). I am on androidx..

```
public static void openActivityNotification(Context context){
    NotificationCompat.Builder nc = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    nc.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    nc.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    nc.setAutoCancel(true);
    nc.setContentTitle("Notification Demo");
    nc.setContentText("Click please");

    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_OPEN_ACTIVITY, nc.build());

}
```

How to make it work for on android 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like You are missing a notification channel that is required from Android O and above.
Documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels
Try this sample:

```
 private String CHANNEL_ID;

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        CharSequence channelName = CHANNEL_ID;
        String channelDesc = "channelDesc";
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance);
            channel.setDescription(channelDesc);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            NotificationChannel currChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
            if (currChannel == null)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }




    public void createNotification(String message) {

        CHANNEL_ID = UiUtil.getStringSafe(R.string.app_name);
        if (message != null ) {
            createNotificationChannel();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(UiUtil.getStringSafe(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            Uri uri =RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            mBuilder.setSound(uri);


            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            int notificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/4);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
           }
}
```

Comment: How to click the displaying notification to land in the application(main activity)?